# Most efficient way to rename and change property/values in javascript

Tags: javascript, native

here is my problem.

How can I do to create the B objet from the A object ? As fast as possible in native js, (I don't care about old browsers, I can use any new javascript things).
Ofc the conversation can be very very longer...

```js
    var objectA = [
      {text: 'Hello you', sender_name:'Indiana Jones'},
      {text: 'What are you doing', sender_name:'Indiana Jones'},
      {text: 'Nothing and you ?', sender_name:'Han Solo'},
      {text: 'I have covid...', sender_name:'Indiana Jones'},
      {text: 'it wont be better soon', sender_name:'Rick Deckard'}
    ]

    var objectB = {
      conversation: [
        {text: 'Hello you', sender_ID: 0},
        {text: 'What are you doing', sender_ID: 0},
        {text: 'Nothing and you ?', sender_ID: 1},
        {text: 'I have covid...', sender_ID: 0},
        {text: 'it wont be better soon', sender_ID: 2}
      ],
      names: {0: 'Indiana Jones', 1: 'Han Solo', 2: 'Rick Deckard'}
    }
```

Edit: for now here how i add the messages in the b object (the variables don't have the same name but you hve the idea). This method is nice because I don't know all keys in the A object. For exemple, There one message can have a third or a fourth property that other messages don't have. But I feel like it could be optimized.

```js
for(const msg in msgs){
    this.msgs.push(msgs[msg]);
    this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].time = this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].timestamp_ms;
    delete this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].timestamp_ms;
    for(const someone in this.people){
        if(this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].sender_name == this.people[someone]){
            this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].author = someone;
            delete this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].sender_name;
        }
    }
      
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a help site, not a code writing service. Pls show your work

Comment: You're right sorry, I've updated my question with what I've done for now

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objectA = [
    {text: 'Hello you', sender_name: 'Indiana Jones'},
    {text: 'What are you doing', sender_name: 'Indiana Jones'},
    {text: 'Nothing and you ?', sender_name: 'Han Solo'},
    {text: 'I have covid...', sender_name: 'Indiana Jones'},
    {text: 'it wont be better soon', sender_name: 'Rick Deckard'}
];
const conversion = arr => {
    const arr1 = [...new Set(arr.map(val => val.sender_name))]
    const names = {...arr1};
    return {
        conversation: arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
            const index = arr1.findIndex(item => item===val.sender_name)
            return acc.concat({text: val.text, sender_ID: index})
        }, []),
        names
    }
}
console.log(conversion(objectA))
```

Comment: Whaou ! It seams very nice ! I need to test it but it looks promising thank you !

Comment: Is that the answer you were looking for? Give a praise

Comment: It's perfectly working but it's slower than what i do for now. And it doesn't support the possibility that there is other properties which needs to be duplicated. But you're answsering my question so +1